# PJAX: Remember additional object states

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I'm currently implementing PJAX on my site and it is working great for the content which is loaded.

But is there also a possibility to remember states of other objects?

In my example if have a SELECT-box which triggers a PJAX-request on change. The content loads fine and when i use backward navigation the content is replaced by the content it had before. Unfortunately, the SELECT-box doesn't change back to its previous value.

Is there a way of implementing that?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `popstate` event handler. With `jquery-pjax` you can bind to the `pjax:popstate` event. Fill in the following code to match your page:

```
$(document).bind("pjax:popstate", function(e) { 
  /* select the option of the SELECT-box that matches current document.URL */
});
```